# 3.7 to 3.3V regulation

Tags: voltage-regulator, lipo, ldo, 3.3v

I want to power up my ESP32 with LiPo battery. LiPo Battery has voltage between 3.7 to 4.2V and ESP32's operating voltage range is 2.2 to 3.6V (but I want it to be 3.3V) and it consumes around 600mA.

My access to LDOs are very limited. Is there any suggestions how to power it? All available buck converters have more than 1V drop out. Should I use voltage dividers?

Comment: What website will you buy from?

Comment: Voltage dividers do not regulate. At all.

Comment: Well, all websites like DigiKey or Mouser are banned in my country...

Comment: Add a diode in series. It will eat up 0.7V (or less, depending on the diode kind)

Comment: An LDO is what you really want here.  However, if your current draw is fairly constant, and your regulation requirements aren't too stringent, you could probably find a Schottky diode with a 0.4V drop at 600mA.  It's probably a good idea to put a load resistor of 1K or less to make sure you draw enough current for at least 0.1V drop in any case (preferably .3V for safety margin), so you don't overvoltage your 3.6V max circuitry.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thats an applicable suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: If digikey and mouser are not available, that's an opportunity for a local supplier, so there must be one you can use.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I will try it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @bobflux All available converters has more than 1v drop.

Comment: With all the limitations you have of sourcing components I would just add an extra cell (higher voltage) and go for the available switched regulator. The Adafruit Feather uses an AP2112 (0.25V dropout) LDO that would have worked, but it's probably not available to you.

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 Good advice. I considered it but then I figured problems with charging it are more complicated!

Comment: A boost-buck converter would do what you need. A little less efficient, but you get 3.3V out from *any* (within reason) input voltage.

Comment: Sure, but 2 cell chargers and battery packs are possible to buy even in your country, no?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 Yes sir you're right. but I have to keep cost, weight and size at minimum. I used a diode to drop about .6v and it's working fine for now. I learned a lot from you and my other SE friends. Thank you all!